# Titanium android different orientation lock between tablet and phone

Tags: android, titanium, orientation, appcelerator

I'm using Titanium, my app supports tablets and phones. For phones I need to use PORTRAIT orientation anche for tablets LANDSCAPE.

I tried to configure android:screenOrientation="nosensor" in tiapp.xml importing all activities from AndroidManifest.xml and orientationModes : [Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT] in window configuration in tablet case, but I have no results. All orientations are active.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty forward with following points:

- Since you need to change orientations at runtime, you cannot control it from tiapp.xml unless you create separate builds for phones and tablets which I believe is not the case.
- Leave tiapp.xml as default and do not set any orientation there.
- Use below snippet for handling it inside `app.tss` file.

  ```
  "Window[if=Alloy.isTablet]" : {
      orientationModes : [Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT, Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT]
  }

  "Window[if=Alloy.isHandheld]" : {
      orientationModes: [Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT, Ti.UI.PORTRAIT]
  }
  ```
- This solution will work only if you create Window controllers using XML, not by using Classic JS.

Double check your code to not to set orientations anywhere else to avoid any issues.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have discovered `activity.requestedOrientation = Titanium.Android.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;` to set into activity of TabGroup that contain my window. It seems it works.